# How to start bash and immediately "type" command into it?

Tags: command-line, bash, command-history

I want bash to first execute a command, but after the command finishes (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'ed) go into interactive mode (preferrably with the command in history, available for <kbd>up</kbd>).

How to attain it in easiest and the most beautiful way?

Inspired by cmd.exe's `/K`:

```
$ wineconsole cmd.exe /K echo qqq
qqq

Z:\home\wine>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaner version of the [Scott's answer](https://superuser.com/a/547079/27264):

1. Put this to `.bash_profile`:

   ```
   if [ ! -z "$EXECUTE_COMMAND" ]; then
       history -s "$EXECUTE_COMMAND"
       $EXECUTE_COMMAND
   fi
   ```
2. Start bash this way:

   ```
   $ EXECUTE_COMMAND='ping 127.0.0.1' bash -l
   PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.177 ms
   ...
   ^C
   5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3996ms
   $
   $ ping 127.0.0.1
   ```

Comment: Good cleanup.  I’m glad to see that `history –s` works in `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not 100% sure that I understand exactly what you’re asking for, and (alas) I don’t have access to a system with `bash` on it at the moment, but maybe the following will help you.  Put this at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_initial_command ]
then
    . ~/.bash_initial_command
    rm ~/.bash_initial_command
fi
```

(where `.bash_initial_command` is an arbitrary filename; pick a different one if you want), and then write a script that does this:

```
(echo "history –s '$@'"; echo "$@") > ~/.bash_initial_command
```

I.e., this puts the command (that is presented to the above script as argument(s)) in a place where the next interactive `bash` to start will find it and execute it.  (E.g., if you run `set_up_cmd ls –l`, then your next `bash` will run `ls –l`.)  `history –s` puts a command into history without executing it.
***Note:*** I do not know whether this will work from `.bashrc`.

This will need more refinement if you will want to use commands with quotes (i.e., quoted special characters) or redirection (`<` or `>`); or compound commands (i.e., containing `;`, `|`, `&&`, or `||`).

A minor problem: if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the command, that will probably terminate the `.bashrc` processing and thereby prevent the `.bash_initial_command` file from being deleted.  You can probably handle that by doing

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_initial_command ]
then
    mv ~/.bash_initial_command ~/.bash_initial_command.$$
    trap "rm -f ~/.bash_initial_command.$$" 0
    . ~/.bash_initial_command.$$
    rm -f ~/.bash_initial_command.$$
fi
```

This gives `.bash_initial_command` a unique name, so as to avoid collisions, and arranges that it will be deleted when the shell exits.

If you need to be able to fire up several of these simultaneously, consider building the “tty” name `$(basename $(tty))` into the `.bash_initial_command` filename.

Of course, doing this makes it all the more important to be sure that your home directory is not writable by anybody but yourself.

Comment: A bit quirky...

Comment: @Vi.: You don’t want to know how sausage is made, either.  But does it do what you want?

Comment: Now looking how to make it as more or less simple script without .bash_profile hackery.

Comment: Done (without \`tty` or .bash_initial_command, although still with .bash_profile)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the command to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. It will run as soon as you open a new window or login to your machine.

See [this](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) page on the differences between the two files.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to start a new bash process from a command line that is already started, pass in the command as a parameter, then stay within that bash process after the command is complete?

Comment: Yes. Actually I want to start gnome-terminal with several tabs pre-opened, but where I can Ctrl+C and restart (probaby with added parmeters) commands easily.